# Android Studio remove default fragment title

Tags: android, user-interface

[image]

How can a developer remove the default fragment panel text. I have not coded Android since version 2.1. Using Android Studio 3.5. My menu/title page is "Tools to help you grow"; beneath that the panel has "This is tools Fragment" which is dynamically loaded into the AVD Manager device when I test the opening app.

The problem:

How to remove panel text: "This is tools Fragment". I never entered this text anywhere inside the project. My title "Tools to help your grow" is correct and should be on this page.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't made in changes in the App's code.

The most simple way to find and remove text is using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (Find in project path) feature of the android studio.

Search `Tools to help you grow` this and remove it. Do the same for any other text you want to remove.

Comment: the text "This is tools Fragment" was not entered by me in the xml or code. there is no find matching "This is tools Fragment". It appears to be automatic generated dynamic display

Answer (score 0):

TextView.visibility=invisible

I missed this TextView on my initial test. It had TextView.text set to  blank, that's why text: "This is tools Fragment" was never visible in the code / xml.

Answer (score 0):

This text is simply specified for Fragments.
You can find this text at

**Project > Java > com.yourpackage > ui > home/gallery/slideshow > ViewModels**